# Root able to access tomcat server using localhost, regular user unable to access tomcat using localhost

Tags: configuration, tomcat

I have a Tomcat `8.5.x` web server running.

When I am logged in as root and open my web browser, I am able to navigate my tomcat web server pages using, for example, `localhost/index.html`

However, if I am logged in as a regular user I get a server does not exist error using `localhost/index.html`, but if I put instead `[ipaddress]/index.html` I can navigate the web server.

What could be causing this issue? Also I can **not** post the configuration files for reasons outside of my control.

Answer (score 1):

There is a large number of possible explanations for those symptoms. The two most obvious ones are:

- You have configured the browser differently on the two accounts.
- The permissions on `/etc/hosts` are incorrect.

In order to investigate further I recommend the following steps.

- Verify that both users can read `/etc/hosts` and get the same contents by typing

  ```
  cat /etc/hosts
  ```
- Try accessing the URL with a different client such as `wget`, `curl`, or a different browser.
- If the two accounts see different results even when using `wget` and `curl` try to inspect the system calls performed and the results seen on each account to identify the difference. If you are using Linux you can use `strace` to do that, other systems have similar tools.